# When i try to install curl, I write sudo apt install curl, the process gets completed, but when I write curl, it shows that curl is not installed

Tags: apt, software-installation, curl

This is what I ran which worked:

`sudo apt install curl`

but when running the command alone it does not work:

`curl`

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, check again please

Comment: Hi @AdeenaLathiya actually the install process never completed successfully. Look at the last lines, it failed to download and install curl. You need to follow the instructions mentioned exactly at the end that state to run sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Comment: @adeena-lathiya If you read the last few lines carefully, it says, `failed to fetch libcurl4_7.58 and curl_7.58 packages`. For some reason the packages are not being downloaded. The last line ask you to try `sudo apt update OR sudo apt install --fix-missing`.

Comment: Are you using some proxy?

Comment: What do u mean by term proxy? I am sorry i am new at this

Comment: Some kind of VPN or restricted internet access, for example, some organisation's internet. What do you get when you run `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb`? Moreover, please paste the error message directly in the question body instead of posting screenshot. This improves readability on slower connections and text only browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your curl isn't getting installed although the process is getting completed (look at the last 3 lines). The error code 403 as rightly pointed out in the comments, and thus either the server is down for maintenance or you're trying to access internet through a proxy that is not allowing you to do so.
This is why it's showing curl not not found!

Comment: The error code was 403 not 404.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry I didn't observe that... Removing my answer now!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the software update. I just updated my ubuntu and now the command has been installed.
Thanks